# Why is this javascript url validator failing?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url

I have the following code to validate if a person entered a "valid" url in a textbox:

```
 function validateURL(textval) {
var urlregex = new RegExp(
    "^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
return urlregex.test(textval);
```

}

a user is getting an error where this is returning false for what seems like a valid urL

```
http://a.website.com/issues/i#browse/TEST-111
```

Can someone confirm why this example wouldn't pass the "valid url" test?

Comment: Why are you requiring a URL to have `www` in it?

Comment: @DenysSéguret — Yes you can. It starts the fragment identifier.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match/validate in the URL? The starting part only, up to `/issues`?

Comment: according to https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex the best would be  from @diegoperini to identify most use cases

Comment: did you notice you are not validating against http without www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone confirm why this example wouldn't pass the "valid url" test?

The main trouble with the regex is that `www.` part is *obligatory* in the pattern.

If you want to make it optional, use a `?` modifier with a group around it (`(?:www\.)?`):

```
^(?:(?:(?:ftp|https?):\/\/)?)(?:www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)*
```

This will match `http://a.website.com` part. To match the whole string, you can use:

```
^(?:(?:(?:ftp|https?):\/\/)?)(www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)*(?:\/[^\/]*)*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oG9kX7/3)

```js
var re = /^(?:(?:(?:ftp|https?):\/\/)?)(www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)*(?:\/[^\/]*)*$/; 
var str = 'http://a.website.com/issues/i#browse/TEST-111';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m[0];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires that the host name portion starts with `www.` (this is not a requirement for URLs in general). The URL you are testing does not include `www.`.

---

There are many other reasons why the regex is broken (you don't test past the first character after `www.`, your attempt to do so bans many characters that are allowed in URLs, etc) but that is why the URL you have isn't passing.